# Facebook Bot for Messenger First App tutorial - firstEntityValue is not defined

Tags: facebook, bots, facebook-messenger

I'm following the Facebook Bot for Messenger First App tutorial found here:
https://wit.ai/docs/quickstart

The case is, after clone the project (https://github.com/wit-ai/node-wit.git) and follow the first steps, when i run the bot, I am getting this error:
firstEntityValue is not defined

My code:

```
'use strict';

const Wit = require('../').Wit;

const token = (() => {
    if (process.argv.length !== 3) {
        console.log('usage: node examples/weather.js <wit-token>');
        process.exit(1);
    }
return process.argv[2];
})();

const actions = {
    say: (sessionId, msg, cb) => {
    console.log(msg);
    cb();
},
merge: (context, entities, cb) => {
    //Retrieve the location entity and store it into a context field
    const loc = firstEntityValue(entities, 'location');
    if(loc) {
       context.loc = loc;
    }
    cb(context);
},
error: (sessionId, msg) => {
    console.log('Oops, I don\'t know what to do.');
},
'fetch-forecast': (context, cb) => {
    // Here should go the api call, e.g.:
    // context.forecast = apiCall(context.location)
    context.forecast = 'cloudy';
    cb(context);
},
};

const client = new Wit(token, actions);
client.interactive();
```

Any help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Had the same problem, found the function defined here https://github.com/wit-ai/node-wit/blob/1c4aedea09332b471d8c45060a1dc1f91f65eff5/examples/joke.js

```
const firstEntityValue = (entities, entity) => {
  const val = entities && entities[entity] &&
    Array.isArray(entities[entity]) &&
    entities[entity].length > 0 &&
    entities[entity][0].value
  ;
  if (!val) {
    return null;
  }
  return typeof val === 'object' ? val.value : val;
};
```

You need to either add this to your index.js or include it as module.

Comment: I submitted a PR to get this added into the repo :)